# How to put accept files limit and limit file size to the DropzoneJS

Tags: laravel, dropzone.js

I have problem on my DropzoneJS configuration setting, I currently experience `Dropzone is not defined` on my console log. I really don't understand why these error happens.

I found the solution I need to use `window.onload` function yes the Dropzone is not defined solved. However the configuration that I set to the Dropzone options is not working even there is no error found.

I will show you guys my sample script that I used for configuring the accepting files and limit of image upload.

Dropzone version: 5.7.0

```
<script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.0/dropzone.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.0/dropzone.css"/>
```

Script:

```
Dropzone.dropzone = {
    acceptedFiles : 'image/*',
};
```

HTML:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div style="margin-top:80px;">
    <div class="container">
        <h4>What are you listing today?</h4>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form action="/BusinessCenterAccount/upload_post_setup" class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
                    @csrf
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header"></div>
                    <div class="card-body"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Output of option configuration:

[image: Output]

As you can see, I add `acceptedFiles` all images only, however I can access folders and other file type.

Comment: @Don'tPanic sorry nope, i already try your answer. i just downgrade the dropzone js. now the function created now working. no error found.

Comment: Did you check the JSFiddle? The code you provided works, using the version of Dropzone you specified, when using the fix I described.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are not actually being applied.  `Dropzone.dropzone` does not do anything, and does not target your form.

[From the docs](https://www.dropzonejs.com/):

> ... if you just have HTML elements with the `dropzone` class, then you don’t programmatically instantiate the objects, so you have to store the configuration somewhere so Dropzone knows how to configure the dropzones when instantiating them.
>
> This is done with the `Dropzone.options` object.

The example there shows:

```
// "myAwesomeDropzone" is the camelized version of the HTML element's ID
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
...
```

Looking at your HTML, your form has an ID `dropzone`.  So to use the syntax the example shows, you should do:

```
Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
    acceptedFiles : 'image/*',
};
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/n6mgq5uf/).  And here's a screenshot of that JSFiddle showing only image files available for selection:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To solved my problem, I just changed my cdnjs version of dropzone to 5.4.0

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/dropzone.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/min/dropzone.min.css">
```

Comment: Great that you solved your problem, but changing Dropzone versions is not what did it.  [Here's a JSFiddle, using v5.4.0, and your original code](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/ycj8adxh/) (check the resources link in the right col, mouse-over the 2 dropzone file to see the URL/version number). Try it! :-)